# What is the best way to organize the categories in this app?

Tags: usability, mobile, feedback, usability-study, mobile-application

I'm developing an iPhone app. This app is really simple: a user can search if (for example) an product contains milk (maybe you are allergic to it) and give you a feedback (you can eat, or you can't eat it).

I had thought to divide the app into 3 parts:

- Home
- Brands
- Categories

While in Brands and Categories I know how I should show it, but in Home I don't know if it's better show some link to the *top* categories, or a list of all products.

I had done a mockups with Balsamiq Mockups that you can see here (click to enlarge):

[image]

Please can you give some feedback and suggest a better organization method? Is it better to show the top (common) categories or all products listing in home (all products can be over 5k also)?

Comment: Thank you for image, but i want leave also the url to pdf that is interactive: http://f.cl.ly/items/3Z1g0C2Y0W0L3k2m3a2h/App_V1.pdf , Anyway feedback ?

Comment: Try something and test it with real users. Otherwise, you're just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the app ready for use right away by setting focus on the search input when the app starts. This will instantly show the keyboard and will hide the bottom menu. Therefore I suggest a different approach for the home screen than for the other screens. Remove the bottom menu and move the "brands" and "categories" buttons above the keyboard:

[image]

Since your app is very simple, it shouldn't be a big issue to break the bottom menu consistency. I guess the "brands" and "categories" buttons are for browsing through the products. In that case you can make that clear by adding a small description or just add the text "Browse..." above them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of static button/tab on bottom on phones screen. It took precious space, better have one more line. They are hidden under keyboard so you need to close the keyboard before using them. I'll prefer them in submenu in the app title bar (maybe right side as you use left for back).
 
Not in the UX side, but If you want to tell user if product may contains something allergic maybe looking at [openfoodfact.org](http://openfoodfacts.org/) for linking or using the database with already some known products where there is field for known allergic.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your app, I think there is a lots of categories that will be commonly searched so you could have something like the most viewed categories on the home screen. To make the navigation through this list easier and quicker to browse, you can use large buttons with icon + label.

I'm not sure if it would be relevant to have a "most viewed products" since you'll probably have a lots of.